# How are a Horizontal Axis Wind Turbine's blades joined to the hub, allowing them to rotate?

Tags: energy, power-engineering, wind-power, wind, power-generation

I know its a basic question for this site.
But I couldn't find the answer on google so I beseech thee.

Answer (score 0):

With bearings to allow rotation so that the blade angle can be controlled and the forces supported.

Variable pitch propellors on airplanes have similar designs just smaller. One wind turbine blade can be the same mass as a medium or large car.

A google (so useful google…) search for "wind turbine hub bearing design" gives this as the top result : https://www.nrel.gov/docs/fy10osti/42362.pdf

Which you should find is a good read.